# How to convert the text to columns in CSV through shell scripting

Tags: shell

I am having a CSV file which is like this.[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kfYF.jpg) with all the values in single column(Column A) delimited by ";"

I need the output file like this.[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzUfB.jpg)

Comment: do not link images: copy a [mcve] as text into the question. Check also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1s/"//g;s/\;/,/g' < input.csv > output.csv
```

---

Test using pseudo-spreadsheet input, with *one* quoted header:

```
echo '----before----' ; \
echo -e '"hey;ho;hi";;\nhey;ho;hi' | tee input.csv ; echo ; \
echo '----after----' ; \
sed '1s/"//g;s/\;/,/g' < input.csv
```

Output:

```
----before----
"hey;ho;hi";;
hey;ho;hi

----after----
hey,ho,hi,,
hey,ho,hi
```

Comment: Thank you so much agc. I have tried your code. Data is spiting to columns Cool !!. But header is coming in a single cell with commas. I need to put the header also in column A column B column C .... like as the data.

Comment: Dear AGC, thank you for your inputs. I am having numeric data also. Once it is saving into CSV all the formats are changing. Like amount (numbers) coming as "1777686.23-" instead of "-1777686.23"  Please let me know how to get this minus sign as a prefix instead of suffix.

Comment: @ramachandrareddy, two additional qualifications means those examples in the original question were unusually _incomplete_.  Please promptly follow fedorqui's advice about examples, re-edit your question, (no  *jpg*s), and we can resume from there.